# Select distinct names from all letters in alphabet

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

**Background**

I have the following sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['ANT J DOE', 'ANT J DOE', 'ANT J DOE', 'ANT J DOE',
                             'ANDREW THE', 'AMANDA TO', 'AZARA HEBREW', 'BARNY GUM',
                             'BORIS CHE', 'BORIS CHE', 'BORIS CHE', 'BRYAN WILLI',
                             'BRAIN THEY', 'BREZ TOW', 'CRAFT CHEEZE', 'ERICE BEE',
                             'ERICK BEE', 'ERIC BRAI', 'ERIK REY', 'FER AZ',
                             'FRAY AR', 'HE SAM', 'JANE ANN DOE', 'JANE ANN DOE',
                             'JAMES J DOE', 'MART DR', 'QUE BALL', 'ZIM THE',
                             'ZIMMY SALLOW', 'ZAQ CRO'],
                   'P_ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
                            20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
                     })
```

**Output**

```
        Name     P_ID
0   ANT J DOE      1
1   ANT J DOE      2
2   ANT J DOE      3
3   ANT J DOE      4
4   ANDREW THE     5
5   AMANDA TO      6
6   AZARA HEBREW   7
7   BARNY GUM      8
8   BORIS CHE      9
9   BORIS CHE     10
10  BORIS CHE     11
11  BRYAN WILLI   12
12  BRAIN THEY    13
13  BREZ TOW      14
14  CRAFT CHEEZE  15
15  ERICE BEE     16
16  ERICK BEE     17
17  ERIC BRAI     18
18  ERIK REY      19
19  FER AZ        20
20  FRAY AR       21
21  HE SAM        22
22  JANE ANN DOE  23
23  JANE ANN DOE  24
24  JAMES J DOE   25
25  MART DR       26
26  QUE BALL      27
27  ZIM THE       28
28  ZIMMY SALLOW  29
29  ZAQ CRO       30
```

**Goal**

Select two distinct names in `Name` from each "alphabet group", A-Z.

Examples:

1) two distinct names from "alphabet group" "A" would correspond to `ANT J DOE` and `ANDREW THE`.

2) Two distinct names from "alphabet group" "Z" would correspond to `ZIM THE` and `ZIMMY SALLOW`

*Importantly, `Name` isn't exhaustive in this example. My real `Name` column has all `26` letters in the alphabet represented*

**Desired Output**

```
        Name     P_ID
0   ANT J DOE      1
1   ANDREW THE     5
2   BARNY GUM      8
3   BORIS CHE     11
4   ERICE BEE     16
5   ERIC BRAI     18
6   FER AZ        20
7   FRAY AR       21
8   JANE ANN DOE  23
9   JAMES J DOE   25
10  ZIM THE       28
11  ZIMMY SALLOW  29
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: is it any 2 or first 2? also by `distinct names in Name from each "alphabet group", A-Z` , do you mean if the name startswith that alphabet?

Comment: So you want to ignore values that *don't* have two distinct values?

Comment: @anky_91 any two `name` works. And yes, here are examples: `a` for `andrew`, `b` for `becky, `c` for `cathy`, `y` for `yasmine` etc

Comment: @user3483203 yes, I want to ignore for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kinda hacky and I'm sure there are better alternatives, but it works:

```
> df['first'] = df['Name'].astype(str).str[0]  # add a column with first letter
> print( df.drop_duplicates('Name'). \         # select distinct names
    groupby('first'). \                        # group by first letter
    filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1). \            # with at least 2 entries
    groupby('first').head(2)[['Name', 'P_ID']] # select Name and P_ID columns
    )


            Name  P_ID
0      ANT J DOE     1
4     ANDREW THE     5
7      BARNY GUM     8
8      BORIS CHE     9
15     ERICE BEE    16
16     ERICK BEE    17
19        FER AZ    20
20       FRAY AR    21
22  JANE ANN DOE    23
24   JAMES J DOE    25
27       ZIM THE    28
28  ZIMMY SALLOW    29
```

Comment: @andrew if I wanted to have the following output in a new column, would it look like this `df['NewName'] = df.drop_duplicates('Name').groupby('first').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).groupby('first').head(2)[['Name', 'P_ID']]` ?

Comment: You'd want to save the output as new dataframe, rather than as an extra column - it wouldn't really make sense to save the entire new table as a column.

eg `two_distinct = df.drop_duplicates('Name').groupby...` Or, if you don't need the unfiltered dataframe anymore, you can reassign df: `df = df.drop_duplicates(...`